Existence of all partial derivatives implies anything about total derivative’s existence?
Say a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is $C^{\infty}$ if its partial derivatives of all orders exist. Does this imply anything about the existence of its total derivatives, or if not then the other way?
What might be relevant is the fact that if a function’s first order partial derivatives all exist and are continuous in a neighborhood around a point, then the total derivative at that point exists. Unfortunately, I’m not sure if it is true that $C^{\infty}$ functions satisfy the hypothesis of this statement.

If all partial derivatives exist and are continuous, then the total derivative exists. The assumption of all partial derivatives to be $C^{\infty}$ is an even stronger requirement.

@Nuffie Am I supposed to use the statement I listed to see this then? I am struggling to see why the existence of all partial derivatives implies they are continuous.

existence of partial derivatives of all orders implies that $\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} \colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function, which implies continuity. Thats why the theorem applies in this case. Note that the converse is not true: There are functions with existing total differential that have discountinuous partial derivatives.

@Nuffie But why if $\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}$ differentiable? All of its partial derivatives exist, but what next? @.math-jl the part you refer to as obvious is the one I'm struggling with. Do you need some fact about existence of certain partial derivatives implying continuity?

In your statement you say a function is called $C^\infty$ if the partial differentials $\textbf{of all orders}$ exist. "Order" refers to the number of times a function is differentiable. If all orders exist, then the partial differentials have to be differentiable themselves to form the second order.

For an example of a function whose partial derivates exist but which is not even continuous and so in particular not differentiable, see this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/673987/1229873. However, as Nuffie said, the existence of all partial derivates of all order implies that f is (infinitely often) differentiable.

@Nuffie By partial differentials of all orders I mean $\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}$ exists for all $1 \leq i \leq n, j \geq 1$, so this doesn't include the total derivatives. I still don't see why this function is continuous. Is it maybe you are applying the following fact: differentiability implies continuity at a point? But a priori (at least to me), all I know about the function $\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}$ is that all its partial derivatives exist, but nothing about its (total) differentiability.

in that case as math-jl already said, the existence of the total derivative is not guaranteed. There are many counterexamples, a quick search yielded for example https://mathinsight.org/differentiable_function_discontinuous_partial_derivatives

Ohhh, I see now. The more popular definition of $C^{\infty}$ is that each $\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}$ exists and is continuous.

So operating under this new definition of $C^{\infty}$, I see why the first total derivative exists. But what about the higher order total derivatives? Is the second total derivative linked to the second order partial derivatves?
